# react-leaflet seems to cause duplicate render calls with React18

Tags: react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v4

The other day I updated my application to React18 and found that something has changed there in the behavior of react-leaflet.
In my project I wrote a custom wrapper for the leaflet-geocoder, which is then used in the MapContainer

Geocoder:

```tsx
export const Geocoder: FC<{}> = props => {

    //#region --Constants--
    const map: L.Map = useMap();
    const {t, i18n} = useTranslation();
    //#endregion

    //#region --States--


    //#endregion

    //#region --Hooks--
    useEffect(() => {

        Initialize();

    }, []);

    //#endregion

    //#region --Functions--

    const Initialize = (): void => {

        const controller: MapController = new MapController();

        const geocoderControl: GeocoderControl = geocoder({
            geocoder: geocoders.mapbox({
                apiKey: controller.Token,
                geocodingQueryParams: {
                    language: i18n.language
                }

            }),
            defaultMarkGeocode: false,
            placeholder: t("search"),
            errorMessage: t("noResult")
        });

        geocoderControl.on("markgeocode", result => {

            const codingResult: GeocodingResult = result.geocode ?? result;

            map.fitBounds(codingResult.bbox);

            const newPopup: L.Popup = popup()
                .setLatLng(codingResult.bbox.getCenter())
                .setContent(codingResult.html ?? codingResult.name)
                .openOn(map);


        });

        geocoderControl.addTo(map);


    };

    //#endregiony

    //#region --Render--

    return null;

    //#endregion

};
```

Usage in the MapContainer of React-Leaflet:

```tsx
<MapContainer center={props.latLng ?? defaultPosition} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={true}>
                <TileLayer
                    attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    url={mapController.BaseUrl}
                    accessToken={mapController.Token}
                    id={eLayer.STREETS}
                />
                {
                    props.enableGeoCoding ?
                        <Geocoder/>
                        : null
                }
                <Markers latLng={props.latLng} fieldSetter={props.fieldSetter}/>
            </MapContainer>
```

With the 17 version of React, it all worked and gave the following result:
[image: Map with one geocoder]

Which is correct, the map shows only one geocoder.
But now in React18 it looks like this:
[image: two geocoders]

After that I created a profile with the react-devtools and looked there why this renders again, the result was that the `useMap()` hook inside the GeoCoder wrapper seems to change.

Do you know why this hook seems to change since the 18 version, code-wise nothing has changed in my code between React17 and 18.

Comment: When using strict mode in React 18, components are rendered twice in development mode. They render, unmount, and then render again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed by saving a reference to the geocoder, and deleting the control from the map when cleaning up the hook